# Saber que campo es unico

Tags: oracle

Tengo una tabla en oracle Personas,

```
nombre   varchar2 unique
apellido varchar2
edad     int
```

Me gustaría saber cuál es la consulta para saber que campo de la tabla es unico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hola buscando el schema

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE OWNER = 'schemaName'
```

en sql server seria

```
SELECT
 [schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
 [table]  = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]),
 [index]  = name, 
  is_unique_constraint,
  is_unique,
  is_primary_key
FROM sys.indexes
```

recordando que el nombre de esquema generalmente es insensible a mayúsculas y necesita ser entregado en mayúsculas, por ejemplo `WHERE OWNER = 'MYSCHEMA'.

[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110606/show-constraints-from-different-schema-oracle)